# JRadioButtons before every line

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane, jradiobutton

I have this program that reads questions with multiple choice answers from a text file and then displays a random set of them in a JOptionPane (very question in a new Pane). In my text file the questions and the 4 options of answers are all in one line and then I divide them into new lines. Now I want to try to add JRadioButtons before every single answer. Is there someone who can help me. Thank you very much in advance. Here is my code:

```
Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < newRanQues; i++) {

            int randIndex = random.nextInt(32) + 0;
            String randomQuestion = questions.get(randIndex);
            randomQuestions.add(randomQuestion);
            String different = randomQuestion.replaceAll(";", "\n");
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, different, "Question", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

                JRadioButton answerA = new JRadioButton("A) " + answer[0]);
                JRadioButton answerB = new JRadioButton("B) " + answer[1]);
                JRadioButton answerC = new JRadioButton("C) " + answer[2]);
                JRadioButton answerD = new JRadioButton("D) " + answer[3]);

                ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
                group.add(optionA);
                group.add(optionB);
                group.add(optionC);
                group.add(optionD);

                return;
            }
```

Comment: See [*How to Use … Radio Buttons*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html).

Comment: I have seen that but the problem is I do not know how to put the Radio Button exactly before every single answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;

public class RadioButtonExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        init();
    }

    private static void init() {
        // create the jframe
        JFrame jframe = new JFrame("Question");
        // create the answers
        String[] answer = { "red", "green", "yellow", "blue, no, red, no... arrrrrg" };
        // create the radio buttons
        JRadioButton answerA = new JRadioButton("A) " + answer[0]);
        JRadioButton answerB = new JRadioButton("B) " + answer[1]);
        JRadioButton answerC = new JRadioButton("C) " + answer[2]);
        JRadioButton answerD = new JRadioButton("D) " + answer[3]);
        // create the button group
        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
        group.add(answerA);
        group.add(answerB);
        group.add(answerC);
        group.add(answerD);
        // add the question to the jframe
        jframe.add(new JLabel("What is your favorite colour?"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        // create gridbag layout and constraints
        GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();
        // create the panel using the gbl
        JPanel pan = new JPanel(gbl);
        // create the constraints
        GridBagConstraints cons = new GridBagConstraints();
        cons.gridwidth = 1;
        cons.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        // answer 1
        cons.gridx = 0;
        cons.gridy = 1;
        pan.add(answerA, cons);
        // answer 1
        cons.gridx = 0;
        cons.gridy = 2;
        pan.add(answerB, cons);
        // answer 1
        cons.gridx = 0;
        cons.gridy = 3;
        pan.add(answerC, cons);
        // answer 1
        cons.gridx = 0;
        cons.gridy = 4;
        pan.add(answerD, cons);
        // add the panel to the jframe
        jframe.add(pan, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        // show the jframe
        jframe.setSize(400, 400);
        jframe.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```